# Python tkinter not working with empty clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

It is my code to get clipboard text:

```
from tkinter import Tk

def check_clipboard():
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    result = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    return result
```

But there is a problem. If `clipboard` is empty, the script is not running. And the error is like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\youtube\MyScript.py", line 15, in <module>
    result0 = r0.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 970, in selection_get
    return self.tk.call(('selection', 'get') + self._options(kw))
_tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
```

I tried but I did not figure out this error. I try to append some strings with `r.clipboard_append("hello")` but it did not work again. How can I solve this? Adding some strings or checking clipboard is empty.

Comment: Use try/except to catch the exception.

Comment: _" If clipboard is empty, script is not running. "_ - that is not true. Clearly, the script is running. How else would it give you an error?

Comment: Yes it give me an error but my whole script is not running because of it.  I can not solve with try/except.

Comment: Can you show me an example about try/except? @acw1668

Comment: You might want to change the subject line of this question to "not working", not "now working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `try/except` on the line `r.selection_get(...)` to catch the exception as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def check_clipboard():
    r = tk.Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    try:
        return r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
        #return r.clipboard_get()
    except tk.TclError:
        return None
    finally:
        r.destroy()
```

Note 1: you can use `r.clipboard_get()` which is the same as `r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")`.

Note 2: I added the `finally` block in case you don't want the instance of `Tk()` after the function.  Otherwise, remove the `finally` block.

Comment: It is working too, and thank you for your notes :) I was trying to catch 'TclError' and it didn't work but 'tk.TclError' is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When the **clipboard is empty**, a `TclError` is raised, you indeed need to `try/catch` it:

Maybe like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import TclError


def check_clipboard():
    root.withdraw()
    try:
        result = root.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    except TclError:
        # handle the error the way you see fit.
        result = 'the clipboard was empty'
    return result

root = tk.Tk()
print(check_clipboard())
```

To **clear the clipboard**, use `root.clipboard_clear()`

There are no options to **check if the clipboard is empty**, but a small function can do that:

```
def is_clipboard_empty():
    try:
        root.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    except TclError:    # error raised when empty
        return True
    return False
```

[More info](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/clipboard.htm#M8)

Comment: 'from tkinter import TclError' is solved my problem. Thank you very much.